# Network Engineering Community Plagiarism Responsibilities

Tags: discussion

This question is referencing posts, such as [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/9956/3191), that are clearly plagiarizing others work.  In this case, others work on this forum (not to mention horrible formatting).

I have found [some guidance over on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) that gives moderators recourse, but not necessarily for community members.

Is it the duty of community members to modify these posts for original source attribution? Would I be out of line for modifying a post to a quote and reference the original source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community should not *regularly* attribute posts for others; doing so enables continued plagiarism and places the burden of finding / remediation on the community.

It is the author's responsibility to properly quote and attribute their work.

In some cases it may be helpful to proactively attribute work for another person if you are sure that you know what their quoted source was; however in all cases the plagiarism should be flagged so mods can be aware of the problem.  Please include a link to the original source in the flag.

That said, if someone plagiarizes an entire answer and adds nothing substantial of their own, please flag it and let a moderator handle the situation.

Comment: Just to clarify the "all cases...should be flagged" paragraph, while the community has the ability to modify the post they don't have the ability to take any further actions themselves.  If posts aren't flagged to make the moderators aware of the issue, we won't be able to take additional corrective steps when necessary.